# Ajax post response returns empy object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have recently started using Node.js and jQuery and I can't figure out what's wrong in my project.
I have a client application that sends a post request to a node js server; this server gets the datas from the post and performs a query; finally it should send back to the client a json containing the informations retrieved from the previous query. The problem is that the response sent by node js is an empty object( {} ) and I don't know why.
Here my source code:

Node JS:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "",
    user: "",
    password: "",
    database : ''
});


var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(cookieParser());


app.post('/search',function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') { //PUT Only
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data){body += data;});
        req.on('end', function () {
            var post = querystring.parse(body);
            console.log("Dati in ingresso > " + JSON.stringify(post));
            //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
            query("SELECT Nome FROM Mood WHERE Nome LIKE \'" + post.data  + "%\'",res);
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Not POST request")
        res.end();
    }
});

var query = function(q,res) {
    var results = {};

    con.query(q, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        results = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))[0].Nome);
        console.log("Risultati query: ");
        console.log(results);
    });
    res.json(results);
    res.end();
}
app.listen(8888);
```

Client:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#search-box').on('input propertychange', function(e){
        var input = $(this).val();
        var array = ['prova1','prova2','prova3'];
        var ul = $('#results-options ul');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search",
            data: {data : input},
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
                console.log(JSON.parse(d));
            },
            error: function(d) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });

        $('#results-options').show();
    });
    $("#results-options").on('click',function (e) {
        $('this').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    $(document).on('click', function(){
        $('#results-options').hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: because you are using results before it is returned/set in the asynchronous call.

Comment: Try putting `res.json(results); res.end();` in the callback of the `con.query()` call.

Comment: Also, quick question - what is the purpose of `// PUT only` in a `.post()` listener? You really don't even need to check the request type there.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.
The check of the request type has to be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated above, your `query` function is sending back a response before the query to the database has finished. That's why it is coming back empty. I moved the `res.json(results); res.end();` code inside the callback of the DB query.

```
var query = function(q,res) {
    var results = {};

    con.query(q, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        results = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))[0].Nome);
        console.log("Risultati query: ");
        console.log(results);

        // I moved the code here
        res.json(results);
        res.end();
    });
    // Your old code
    // res.json(results);
    // res.end();
};
```